# Symbol Table Prolog

Tags: prolog, global-variables, swi-prolog

I am trying to build a symbol table in Prolog. I have defined two predicates so far but how to use them or correct them goes above my head. I would love some help on how to go about it. Thank you

```
create_empty_table:-
   use_module(library(assoc)),empty_assoc(A),
   b_setval(idex,A).

add_symbol(Key,Value):-
    b_getval(idex,Output),
    get_assoc(Key, idex,Output, idex,[Value|CurrentValue]),
    b.setval(idex,[Value|CurrentValue]).
```

The first one works fine. I have no idea how to use the second one. b_getval gives me an error for insufficient instantiation.

Comment: Seriously: That's not a good start into Prolog.

Comment: `b_getval` requires the name (an *atom*) of a global value you're trying to retrieve. You're passing two uinstantiated variables to `b_getval`, so it doesn't know what name you are referring to. You need to pass the assoc name to `add_symbol`.